# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I know that it is an easy problem but I can't find the error. I want to save data in my database. I create a database named "Examen" with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 then in my app in visual studio I make the connection string like this :

```
string connectionstring = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Examen;Integrated Security=True";
```

Then I use this code to insert data into a "Test" table:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
MySqlCommand cmd;
connection.Open();

try
{
  cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Examen.Test (nom,prenom) values (" + txbnom.Text + "," + txbprenom.Text + ") ";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("ok");
}
catch (Exception)
{
  throw;
}
finally
{ 
  if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

When running this code i had an error when openning the connection

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Comment: MySql and SQLServer are two different beasts

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [MSSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server).

Are you sure you want to connect to a MySQL server? Use [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you would like to connect to MSSQL.

Also you should make yourself familiar with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)